# How to deal with dynamic columns while converting xml to csv

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, automation, converters

I want to parse through Xml file and convert it to Csv , The columns are dynamic between those Dab tags(As we can see there is an `<C>` tag in second section not in the first one though. I want to get id attribs and text for the one which has no id. I tried but not able to figure it our as I'm newbie don't know how to deal with dynamic columns. using python pandas NumPy

```
<Dab action="A" id="94730">
        <A id="18953"/>
        <B id="2112"/>
        <No>1</No>
        <D id="8920"/>
        <E id="1"/>
        <Num>000-000</Num>
    </Dab>
    <Dab action="A" id="94731">
        <A id="18958"/>
        <B id="269"/>
        <C id="2112"/>
        <No>1</No>
        <D id="8920"/>
        <E id="1"/>
        <Num>419-000</Num>
</Dab>
```

This is result i want to get at the end
**[image: strong text]**

Comment: Please post your current code

Comment: Your xml file is not valid. Check it here: https://www.xmlvalidation.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a well-structured xml, try `xmltodict`:

```
import xmltodict

xml_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_data)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(xml_dict)
```

Example:

```
xml_data = """
<questionaire>
<question>
    <questiontext>Question1</questiontext>
    <answer>Your Answer: 99</answer>
</question>
<question>
    <questiontext>Question2</questiontext>
    <answer>Your Answer: 64</answer>
</question>
<question>
    <questiontext>Question3</questiontext>
    <answer>Your Answer: 46</answer>
</question>
<question>
    <questiontext>Bitte geben</questiontext>
    <answer_not_in_others>Your Answer: 544</answer_not_in_others>
    <answer>Your Answer: 943</answer>
</question>
</questionaire>
"""

xml_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_data)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(xml_dict['questionaire']['question'])

df
```

Output:

[image: Example output]

Fixing your example (Added a top tag):

```
xml_data = """
<master>
    <Dab action="A" id="94730">
        <A id="18953"/>
        <B id="2112"/>
        <No>1</No>
        <D id="8920"/>
        <E id="1"/>
        <Num>000-000</Num>
    </Dab>
    <Dab action="A" id="94731">
        <A id="18958"/>
        <B id="269"/>
        <C id="2112"/>
        <No>1</No>
        <D id="8920"/>
        <E id="1"/>
        <Num>419-000</Num>
    </Dab>
</master>
"""

xml_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_data)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(xml_dict['master']['Dab'])
```

Output:

[image]

After that you can extract the id values for some columns.

```
for col in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']:
    df[col] = list(map(lambda x: x.get('@id') if type(x) is dict else np.nan, df[col]))
```

Output:

[image]